# Carnet de Passages when entering Iran via Turkey

Tags: borders, iran, carnet-de-passage

We attempt to drive into Iran from Turkey via Bazargan border. We hold the Lithuanian citizenship and have a valid visa for the Iran. We passed the Turkey control and are currently stuck between the border of Turkey and Iran.

We hear and read so many different opinions regarding entering Iran with a car. We perfectly understand, that this can be done by "fixers" at the border, but the price is around $500, so obviously we want to attempt to do it cheaper than that. Can someone clarify the following:

- Is Carnet de Passage required for the citizens of European Union?
- Is it possible to organize Carnet de Passage on our own? If so, is it correct that much bigger amount of money will be required as a deposit?

Comment: You are currently sitting between the borders and are asking this now?  Does not one get a CDP from their home country before traveling?

Comment: Yes, we at the border. CDP could be arranged at home, but it would require relatively big deposit.

Comment: Yes it's required. Some links that might be helpful: https://goo.gl/s8wCyo + https://goo.gl/UzkRUd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Is Carnet de Passage required for the citizens of European Union?**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnet_de_Passages_en_Douane#Asia_.26_Middle_East), yes.

> **Is it possible to organize Carnet de Passage on our own?**

Yes but in Lithuania if there is an automobile organisation there willing to provide the service and to be liable for four or five times the vehicle's value?

Some organisations take [several weeks](http://www.carseurope.net/carnet-de-passage-en-douanes-cpd-frequently-asked-questions/) to issue the document.

> **If so, it is correct that much bigger amount of money will be required as a deposit?**

More than $500? probably. There are also other fees.

> the owner of the items is required to provide a security based on the countries traveled to, age and market value of the items.

This might be one of those situations where to get it done cheaply, you need to plan in advance. It might also be true that being stuck in no-man's land between Turkey and Iran puts you at a negotiating disadvantage with the local fixers.

Comment: Starting from the current situation, between the borders with a car and without a carnet, does the OP have any realistic alternative to paying a local fixer?

Comment: @Patricia: I can only guess. If blessed with charm and linguistic skills they might cut out the criminal middlemen and bribe the corrupt officials directly themselves at lower cost than paying the "fixer" to slip them their backhanders. I'm too risk-averse to suggest such a course of action. I'd worry about carrying into Iran forged/improperly-obtained documents, or absence of correct-documents. that could be construed as evidence of bribery  and inviting further extortion or prosecution deeper in Iran. Maybe I'm being overly alarmist though.